# How to paginate correctly in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, vuex

The problem I have is that my paginator always shows that the value of `total: items.length` is equal to 20, which is incorrect, I'm using a custom api that I implement that has data for more than 10 pages, so it's impossible for the total is 20 data.

**Dev tool**

Here I show the output in devtool, making it clear that my API has endpoints that have more than 10 pages with data.

If you notice, it only says that you only have 20 data, which is impossible.

```
data: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
next_page: 2
page: 1
per_page: 10
pre_page: null
total: 20
total_pages: 2
```

I'll thank you for some help.

**Pagination**

```
export const paginator = (items, page, per_page) => {
  var page = page || 1,
  per_page = per_page || 10,
  offset = (page - 1) * per_page,

  paginatedItems = items.slice(offset).slice(0, per_page),
  total_pages = Math.ceil(items.length / per_page),

  paginContent = {
    page: page,
    per_page: per_page,
    pre_page: page - 1 ? page - 1 : null,
    next_page: (total_pages > page) ? page + 1 : null,
    total: items.length,
    total_pages: total_pages,
    data: paginatedItems
  };
  console.log("Paginate Item: ", paginatedItems);
  console.log("Pagin Content: ", paginContent);
  return paginContent.data;
};
```

**Actions.js**

```
 GET_ANIME_ALPHA({commit} , info){
    A.get(`${API_URL_ENDPOINT.letter}` + "/" + info.letter + "/" + info.page)
      .then((res) =>{
        const animes = res.data.animes;
        //console.log("\n⚠️ ANIME BY LETTER (res): " , animes);
        const dataPaginated = pagin.paginator(animes , info.page , 10);
        commit('SET_ANIME_ALPHA' , dataPaginated);
        commit('IS_LOADING' , false);
      }).then((err) =>{
        console.log(err);
    });
  },
```

**AnimeByLetters.vue**

```
<template>
  <!-- all content -->
  <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col bg-white overflow-hidden">
    <!-- top bar -->
    <div class="border-b flex px-6 py-2 items-center flex-none">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <h3 class="text-grey-darkest mb-1 font-extrabold"> Animes by Letter</h3>
            <div class="text-grey-dark text-sm truncate">
               Enjoy the world of anime 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-1 justify-center hidden sm:flex">

        </div>
        <!-- href links to platforms and social media -->
        <div class="flex justify-start items-center text-gray-500">
          <h1>Alphabet</h1>
          <select class="list-reset border border-purple-200 rounded m-3 w-20 font-sans" v-model="letter">
            <option v-for="(char , index) in options"
              :value="char"
              :key="index"
            >
              {{char}}
            </option>
          </select>

          <a href="https://github.com/ChrisMichaelPerezSantiago/ryuanime" class="block flex items-center hover:text-gray-700 mr-5">
            <svg class="fill-current w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
              <title>GitHub</title>
              <path d="M10 0a10 10 0 0 0-3.16 19.49c.5.1.68-.22.68-.48l-.01-1.7c-2.78.6-3.37-1.34-3.37-1.34-.46-1.16-1.11-1.47-1.11-1.47-.9-.62.07-.6.07-.6 1 .07 1.53 1.03 1.53 1.03.9 1.52 2.34 1.08 2.91.83.1-.65.35-1.09.63-1.34-2.22-.25-4.55-1.11-4.55-4.94 0-1.1.39-1.99 1.03-2.69a3.6 3.6 0 0 1 .1-2.64s.84-.27 2.75 1.02a9.58 9.58 0 0 1 5 0c1.91-1.3 2.75-1.02 2.75-1.02.55 1.37.2 2.4.1 2.64.64.7 1.03 1.6 1.03 2.69 0 3.84-2.34 4.68-4.57 4.93.36.31.68.92.68 1.85l-.01 2.75c0 .26.18.58.69.48A10 10 0 0 0 10 0">
              </path>
            </svg> 
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- content inside -->
    <div class="px-6 py-4 flex-1 overflow-y-scroll scrollbar" id="style-1">
      <div v-if="isLoading">
        <div class="lds-roller"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-wrap" v-else>
        <div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/2 xl:w-1/2 mb-4" v-for="(anime , index) in animesByAlpha" :key="index">
          <LatestAnime :anime="anime"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <paginate
      class="paginator-container list-reset border border-purple-200 rounded w-auto font-sans"
      v-model="page"
      :page-count="animesByAlpha.length"
      :page-range="3"
      :margin-pages="2"
      :click-handler="pageHandler"
      :prev-text="'Prev'"
      :next-text="'Next'"
      :container-class="'pagination'"
      :page-class="'page-item'">
    </paginate>


    <!-- footer -->
    <Footer/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Footer from "./Footer"
  import LatestAnime from '../components/LatestAnime'
  import {mapState , mapGetters} from 'vuex'
  import store from '../store/store'

  export default {
    name: "AnimesByLetter",
    components:{
      LatestAnime,
      Footer
    },
    data(){
      return{
        page: 0,
        searchModel: '',
        letter: "a",
        options: [...Array(26).keys()].map(i => String.fromCharCode(i + 97)) //[a .. z]
      }
    },
    computed:{
      ...mapState(['animesByAlpha' , 'isLoading']),
    },
    watch:{
      "letter": function(value){
        this.letter = value;
        let letter = this.letter;
        let info = {letter: letter , page: this.page}
        store.dispatch('GET_ANIME_ALPHA' , info);
      }
    },
    created(){
      let info = {letter: this.letter , page: this.page}
      store.dispatch('GET_ANIME_ALPHA' , info)
    },
    methods:{
      pageHandler(){
        try{
          let info = {letter: this.letter , page: this.page}
          store.dispatch('GET_ANIME_ALPHA' , info)
        }catch(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: `data: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]` doesn't mean there are 10 pages of data. That is ***the actual data*** of current page (10 items). Each `{...}` is one item and if you click on it you'll see what it contains (in dev tools console). The backend you're using is pretty helpful, giving you both the total number of items and the total number of pages (typically you have to calculate the total number of pages yourself).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Here I leave an api endpoint that I implement:
https://ryuanime-api.chrismichael.now.sh/api/v1/letter/b/7

The content limit per page for this is 7 pages.
If I try it in my program, it only tells me 20 data, which are 2 pages. In the front end, if I move to the 3rd page I get the empty content. And it's supposed to show me more content.